# How to hide the keypad after use

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Hei, is there an easy way to add -  that after the input into a text field and pressing a button the keypad is disappearing from the screen?

I found here this answer:  in button action routine write [yourTextField resignFirstResponder]. it will hide your keyboard.

But I dont get it where to place that code `[yourTextField resignFirstResponder]`

Thanks for help!

Comment: Look at `textFieldShouldReturn:` `UITextFieldDelegate` method?

Comment: Could you give me a full code? I dont get it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply want to dismiss the keyboard when the user presses the return key, simply add this to `viewDidLoad` in order to receive delegate callbacks from your textfield:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.myTextfield.delegate = self;
}
```

And then implement this method that hides the keyboard when the user presses the return key:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return NO;
}
```

And in Swift:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad() 
   myTextfield.delegate = self
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField!) -> Bool {
   textField.resignFirstResponder()
   return false
}
```

If you're not pressing the return key, but your own UIButton, you'll have to do something like this:

```
@IBAction func findBudget(sender: AnyObject) {
    myTextfield.resignFirstResponder()

    // .. rest of your code.
}
```

Comment: I updated my answer to include the Swift variant. Sorry I didn't notice your Swift tag in the first round.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I added the code, but nothing happens when I am finished editing in the text box and press the button :(

Comment: @HajoHansen Which button do you press when you're done editing?

Comment: `@IBAction func findBudget(sender: AnyObject)`

Comment: @HajoHansen Okay, I assume you're not pressing the return key on the keyboard, but on your own UIButton. I've added an example of this to my answer.